# How to put a table into a QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt

I actually have two questions:

- Can I have a "Show details" button elsewhere in a QMessageBox (like in a QDialog for exemple)?
- How can I put a tableWidget into a QMessageBox?

Comment: At first sight it looks too complicated for the qmessagebox which is just supposed to display a short message. It should not be hard to create a QDialog to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example code for put a tableWidget into a QMessageBox.
If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.__init__(self)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled (True)   

        self.setWindowTitle ('Hello MessageBox ???')

        #Create QPushButton in QMessageBox        
        self.addButton (QtGui.QPushButton('Accept'), QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole)
        self.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Reject'), QtGui.QMessageBox.NoRole)
        self.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel'), QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)      

        #Add TableWidget to QMessageBox           
        self.addTableWidget (self) 

        #Return values while clicking QPushButton        
        currentClick    = self.exec_() 

        if currentClick==0 :
            print 'Accept'            
        if currentClick==1 :
            print 'Reject'            
        if currentClick==2 :
            print 'Cancel'

    #Create TableWidget 
    def addTableWidget (self, parentItem) :    
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(parentItem)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 540, 250))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName ('tableWidget')

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6) 

    #Allow resizing of QMessageBox
    def event(self, e):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.event(self, e)
        self.setMinimumWidth(0)
        self.setMaximumWidth(16777215)
        self.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.setMaximumHeight(16777215)        
        self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.resize(550, 300)

        return result    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyMessageBox ()
    #ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

#Thanks, 
#Subin Gopi
```

Answer (score 0):

Executed in PyQt5 and adding layout of the table widget instead calling QRect.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.__init__(self)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled (True)

        self.setWindowTitle('Hello MessageBox ???')
        self.setIcon(self.Question)
        self.setText("Hello MessageBox")
        self.addButton (
            QtWidgets.QPushButton('Accept'), 
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.YesRole
        )
        self.addButton(
            QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reject'), 
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoRole
        )
        self.addButton(
            QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel'), 
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole
        )

        self.addTableWidget (self)

        currentClick = self.exec_()

        if currentClick==0 :
            print ('Accept')
        if currentClick==1 :
            print ('Reject')
        if currentClick==2 :
            print ('Cancel')

    def addTableWidget (self, parentItem) :
        self.l =  QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(parentItem)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName ('tableWidget')

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.move(30,80)
        self.tableWidget.resize(500, 170)
        self.l.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    def event(self, e):
        result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.event(self, e)
        self.setMinimumWidth(0)
        self.setMaximumWidth(16777215)
        self.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.setMaximumHeight(16777215)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.resize(550, 300)

        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyMessageBox ()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

output:

[image]